# I'm searching a 3d carousel component for react js like this one: react-carousel3

Tags: reactjs, window, carousel

I'm working with this component: https://github.com/xiaxiangfeng/react-carousel3d#readme and with React JS and Netlify CMS.

It works until I reload the page. As soon as I reload the page the error "ReferenceError: window is not defined" occurs. I could not solve it. Where is the problem or how can I fix this error? The two screenshots I added you can see how its working and then the error.
[the working 3d slideshow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQlnM.jpg)[and the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vFrv.jpg)

I tried to load it differently like instead of
`import { Carousel } from 'react-carousel3'; var Carousel = require( 'react-carousel3').Carousel;`

and also
`if (typeof window !== "undefined") { // Client-side-only code console.log("jetzt nicht undefined") }`
before the return ( codeline